# Putting image tags into php

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hello im using page nation which is amazing but now im trying to print off there avaratar im using this code

```
echo "<IMG SRC=\"$list['avatar']\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\"
BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" \/>";;
```

but im getting this error

> > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in test.php on line 64

Comment: `echo "<IMG SRC=\"{$list['avatar']}\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\"
BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" \/>";`

Comment: Please learn what those error messages mean, especially try to learn about the term "syntax error". This is very useful if you need to deal with code. More example of syntax errors in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+syntax-error

Comment: on sidenote, consider using http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php and put a value for the alt attribute. Its mandatory. Whereas width, height and border would be better specified with CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<IMG SRC=\"".$list['avatar']."\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\"
BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" />";
```

instead, or you could use this one, too

```
echo "<IMG SRC=\"{$list['avatar']}\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\"
BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" />";
```

or better and readable ones:

```
echo '<IMG SRC="'.$list['avatar'].'" WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176" BORDER="0" ALT="" />';

echo '<IMG SRC="', $list['avatar'], '" WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176" BORDER="0" ALT="" />';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in test.php on line 71  with your code all of them ive tryied 1 by 1 with same error

Comment: Probably because this is not answering the question what a syntax error is, only how to cure it. The next time something similar happens, the asker will pose a similar question again.

Comment: @hakre: Okay, I can try to explain it a bit more next time

Comment: @genesis φ: The error you spotted might not be the cause of the syntax error the asker is seeing. As I wrote: The next time a syntax error happens, your answer did not help much. It's just that. Technically your code looks right, but it's not helpful as an answer ;)

Comment: @hakre, although technically your point is extremely correct, in practice *they* don't want no explanations but all thay want is working code.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yeah I'm aware of the problems we face in this age ;)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: yes, that's also the fact

Comment: @user967149: It's common practice that you explain in your own words, what the cause of the error was, so to share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this

```
echo "<IMG SRC=\"$list[avatar]\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\" BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" />";
```

eliminate de braces surrounding the variable and the single quotes for the array key

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
echo "<IMG SRC=\"{$list['avatar']}\" WIDTH=\"268\" HEIGHT=\"176\" BORDER=\"0\" ALT=\"\" />";
```

...or, less confusingly:

```
echo '<IMG SRC="'.$list['avatar'].'" WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176" BORDER="0" ALT="" />';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in test.php on line 71   with your code

Answer (score 1):

this should work :

```
echo '<IMG SRC="'.$list['avatar'].'" WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176"
BORDER="0" ALT="" />';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in test.php on line 71   with your code

Comment: I have a feeling that the error is not from this line, because you posted that on all the answers and the above code is correct!!! the code works here http://wecircled.com/lab/id/imgtest.php

Answer (score 1):

to avoid all thet mess

```
?><IMG SRC="<?=$list['avatar']?> " WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176" BORDER="0" ALT="" /><?php
```

and **don't** post your usual "parse error" comment here.
but check your **other** PHP syntax issue somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
echo '<IMG SRC="'.$list['avatar'].'" WIDTH="268" HEIGHT="176" BORDER="0" ALT="" />';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in test.php on line 71   with your code